# Why do my CSS elements not align with the top of the web page?

Tags: html, css

For some reason, the element I have in the example image will not align with the top of the page. I haven't worked with HTML/CSS in awhile but I can't see anything coding-wise that would shift the rectangle down ~5px. [image]

I'm trying to achieve the bar on this page: http://gradients.glrzad.com/

Here's my code.
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE "html">
<html>
<head>
<title>Mobile Site</title>
<link href="mobileCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="titleBar">
<strong>Coles Web</strong>
</div>
<div id="container">



</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

body{
    background-color:#666;
}
#container{
    width:auto;

}

#titleBar{
    position:fixed;
    position:relative;
    width:auto;
    height:15px;
    text-align:left;
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    font-size:small;
    color:#00FFFF;
    background-color:#000;
    box-shadow:0 3px 5px #333333;
    border-bottom-left-radius:3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:3px;
}


.bubble{
    width:auto;
    height: 40px;
    position:relative;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    background-color:#0FF;
    border-radius:3px;
    font-family:Impact, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;

}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Set the padding and margin on the body to zero. Better yet, use a CSS reset.

Comment: Padding and Margin are now zero and worked like a charm. Thanks  j08691!

Answer (score 2):

```
body{
    background-color:#666;
    padding: 0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to #titlebar:

```
top:0;
left:0;
```

Also, you can only have one position. relative or fixed.